# Graphic Error after closing MessageBox

Tags: .net, wpf, graphics, messagebox

How can I avoid the graphic errors in the following screenshot:
[image: Graphic Error after Closing MessageBox]
The error occurs when a `FileDialog` was opened and a message popped up whether I want to overwrite a file or not. There are some other occasions aswell. I tried `this.InvalidateVisual` and `this.UpdateLayout` but it didn't disappear. It only disappears when I move the window over the bounds of the screen and center it again.

Comment: Does this happen on multiple machines?

Comment: I think so but not 100 percent sure. I had quite a similar problem on Win7 with another program. The label I set had a false value but after moving it out the bounds of the screen and center it again it had the correct value. So it's quite similar. But this one is on WinXP Prof.

Comment: In my experience this is usually caused by some driver problems and/or some problem in the processing of Windows Messages... since you don't provide any details there is not much to go on for an answer...

Comment: Yahia is right. It would be an issue with your video drivers redrawing the screen. I would 1) Check to see that you have the latest video drivers, 2) Look at how much Total Working Set memory and CPU you are utilizing during the running of the application.. You can simulate this behavior by bogging down your system resources and attempting to run any application with pop-ups.

Comment: Where did you find this.Refresh? Is it WPF at all?

Comment: Besides from the hints given above: do you perform some heavy operation in the GUI thread after the file open dialog has been closed? This could lead to such a behavior.

Comment: No I am only saving the filepath and dynamically create a xml file and it's content which leads to a final size of about 3kb. It's not that much.

Answer (score 0):

Had (and perhaps still having) the same problem with our software at work. Seems replacing the graphics adapter and using updated drivers solved it. Of course, some tested adapters/drivers combinations introduced other problems in other parts of the software, so it is really all about finding the sweet spot where hardware and software work together well (unfortunately).

You could always see if using software rendering solves the problem (see more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970912.aspx)). Do it temporarily just to make sure this is really the issue. If so, test other hardware/drivers combos. If not,  let us know ;-).